# How Change Title tags on joomla browser title

Tags: joomla-3.5

I have cloned a website into a different domain and I am trying to change the browser title that shows up in the website tab. I have changed the page display Browser Page Title on the home page module(which was blank), I have changed the page title, its still showing the same title that was on the old website. Where can I go into the code and change the title tags myself? which file changes this?

Answer (score 0):

"Global configuration/Site name" is the site name. Change it. On the same page on the right there is a SEO settings with option "Include site name in page title". I guess that is what you are searching for.